# How to correctly use the GHSL's GHS-BUILT-S data? How can it be converted into a binary image?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I understand that in the latest version of GHS-BUILT-S, each pixel represents the probability of construction. So, how can it be converted into a binary image that only includes built-up and non-built-up areas? I found a paper analyzing GHS-BUILT-S2 data(https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jag.2023.103469) , but is there a general approach for data with a resolution of 100m?